# Why is the first derivative positive even though the graph is decreasing in this interval?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

---

This is from [MIT OCW single variable calculus](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/), in a section about learning to sketch curves. The material explains that if f'(x) is negative then f(x) is decreasing - this makes sense to me geometrically, if the slope of the tangent is negative then the graph is obviously decreasing.

Now for the question:

> Sketch the graph of y = x/(x+4); find the intervals on which it is increasing and decreasing and decide how many solutions there are to y = 0."

And the solution:

> y = x/(x+4), y' = 4/(x+4)^2
>
> Increasing on: -4 < x < infinity
>
> Decreasing on: -infinity < x < -4

I can see that the solution is correct, but as far as I can tell, y' > 0 for all values of x (except x = -4).

Is there something I'm missing, algebraically? Or am I just supposed to look at the graph and infer that this is some special case of y'?

Comment: The function is increasing at every point. Why do you say it is decreasing in $(- \infty , -4)$? This is wrong.

Comment: The function decreases when x < -4

E.g. -5 / (-5 + 4) = -5 / -1 = 5; don't negative numbers divided by negative numbers become positive?

Comment: I don't get your point. You know that $f(-5)=5$, so what?

Comment: @Xianny That´s not true.

Comment: It seems to me that the function is increasing everywhere it is defined.

Comment: The function is strictly increasing on any interval where it is defined. This does *not* mean that it is increasing on $(-5,-3)$ for example, since that interval includes point $-4$ where the function is not defined.

Comment: oh right, that's irrelevant; thanks for pointing that out @Crostul.

That makes sense - I guess the answer sheet is wrong then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The plot shows that the function does increase for every value of $x$.

As your derivative test did.

There is no decreasing behaviour.

Comment: The function is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,-4)$ and $(-4,\infty)$, but it's *not* monotonic on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-4\}$. I think that might be part  of OP's confusion.

Comment: @dxiv You're surely right about the monotony. It seemed me the OP had some issues also with a ghost decreasing part, so I plotted the function to show him at least the trend!

Comment: thanks - getting a computer plotted graph helps me confirm the answer sheet is either wrong or I'm misunderstanding it! that's definitely where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: @Xianny The function does increase for every value of $x$. At $x = -4$ the function is not defined, since the limit $4^+$ and $4^-$ are different. So you can tell the function does increase but not monotonically as dxiv suggested. If you have other doubts, please write them!